# Facebook API - Subscriptions Timeout in callback

Tags: php, facebook, subscriptions, real-time-updates

I have a really strange problem in PHP with the Facebook API. All this code is working in my testing server (shared hosting). But when I run it in the production server (Heroku) I get an error.

What I am trying to do is to receive realtime updates from Facebook when my app users likes (or unlikes) a new page.
This is the documentation that Facebook provides: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates

My code to subscribe:

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => $app_id,
            'secret' => $app_secret,
            'cookie' => true
        ));
  $facebook->api(
                "/" . $app_id . "/subscriptions", "POST", array(
            'object' => 'user',
            'callback_url' => 'http://' . $url . '/rtu/callback',
            'fields' => 'likes',
            'verify_token' => $rtu_verify_token,
            'access_token' => $app_id . "|" . $app_secret
                )
        );
```

My code in the callback:

```
 if (isset($_GET['hub_verify_token']) && isset($_GET['hub_challenge'])) { 
            $rtu_verify_token = Config::get('variables.rtu_verify_token');
            if (($_GET['hub_verify_token'] == $rtu_verify_token)) {
                echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
                die();
            }
        }

        $data = file_get_contents("php://input");

        $json = json_decode($data);
```

The error:

> FacebookApiException (#2200) callback verification failed: Operation
>   timed out after 6001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

I have already verify the app_id, url and the app_secret variables. 
Again, this works in my testing server, but not in Heroku.
I even tried not to use the Facebook API and make a cURL call, but I got the same error.

I'm thinking that maybe has something to do with Heroku, but i couldn't find any evidence.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your server must be reachable from the internet, and be able to process concurrent requests, because facebook sends verification requests simultaneously.

Comment: And Heroku doesn't allow multiple request with only one dyno, Am I right?
Thanks!

Comment: One dyno it's only one virtual server. On server you can runs as much instances as you want)
Here is example of Procfile to run 4 instances of gunicorn:
"web: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; gunicorn -w 4 someapp.wsgi"